# Unable to find the persistence window in Intellij 14.1.4

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've been going through all the documents from `JetBrains`, but couldn't find the Persistence Window for my project so that I could auto generate the Pojo classes for the database tables without manually creating them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, by enabling the persistence configuration. Went to `persistence.xml` which would be ideally located under the `META-INF`, and it would automatically ask you, whether to enable the persistence.

There after from View > Tool Windows, you could find Persistence Window.

Answer (score 3):

You can find any window using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut and typing in `Persistence`. This also tells you if there's any bindings to quickly open that window. Having done this, it doesn't have a keyboard shortcut.

From the menu you can access it by `View` → `Tool Windows` → `Persistence`

As @Bohuslav said in the comments, you need to add a JPA facet to the project for the window to be actionable.

Comment: IIRC you must also add JPA facet in _Project structure_, otherwise the _Persistence_ option will be disbled (greyed out)

Comment: This was tested on 14.1.3 and it doesn't seem as if they've changed in [14.1.4](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+14.1.4+Release+Notes)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Edited in the answer, had JPA Facet's in the project I was in already so it didn't occur to me. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, will work on it and give an update.